# Browser dev tools - Computed vs Rules tabs

Tags: css, safari

Under the "Rules" tab I can see styles that are either directly assigned, inherited or styles that come from "User Agent Stylesheet". As you can see there is no `line-height` set in here. However, when I switch to the "Computed" tab, I can see the `line-height` is 47px. Why is it and where is it coming from? Shouldn't it be located under the "Rules" tab somewhere in the "User Agent Stylesheet"? I don't quite understand how all those rules are categorised, I thought that "User Agent Stylesheet" shows all the default styles for a particular element. However, it looks like this is not the case. Thanks in advance for clearing this up for me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Line-height is usually a function of font-size...how is that calculated in your **very large** image?

Comment: What browser is that, Peter?

Comment: @Paulie_D Under the Rules tab the font-size is 2em. Under the Computed tab the font-size is 32px, converted from ems to pixels. The thing I don't understand is how the properties are categorised. Why is the line-height property under the Computed tab and not under the Rules tab in the User Agent Stylesheet section. It looks like the User Agent Stylesheet section doesn't show all default styles. I thought that any styles not written by me come from the default browser's stylesheet, but this is not the case.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu It is Safari.

Comment: That would suggest that there is a line-height declaration *somewhere* or the default is Safari is, perhaps, c1.4

Comment: @Paulie_D I didn't declare line-height anywhere, so it should be Safari's default I believe. However, if it's a default setting why I can't see it in the User Agent Stylesheet section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is line-height not appearing under Rules tab?**

The `line-height` is not shown in the Rules tab because it is not part of default user-agent stylesheet for `h1` tag. Safari's default user-agent stylesheet can be found [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-1640/css/html.css).

```
h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0.67__qem;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

All properties that you see as defined under the `h1` above are being shown in the Rules tab because they are part of the User Agent's default stylesheet. 
However, the `line-height` is not a part of it and hence doesn't get shown in the Rules tab.

---

**Why is it getting displayed under the Computed tab when it is not part of  UA stylesheet?**

Since there is no value specified for `line-height`, the default value as specified in the spec (which is `normal`) is used. The [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#line-height) says the following:

> A value of 'normal' sets the 'line-height' to a reasonable value for the element's font. It is suggested that UAs set the 'normal' value to be a number in the range of 1.0 to 1.2.

As you can see the specs there place importance on two points which are:

- The `line-height` is set to a reasonable value for the **element's font**. So, the font used plays a key role in determining the `line-height`.
- The spec only ***suggests*** that UAs use 1.0 to 1.2 as a value and not mandates. This means that each UA can determine a number that it finds reasonable for the element's font.

So, each UA ***computes*** the value for `line-height` as it deems appropriate. Since the UA is actually computing the value instead of picking it up from a default stylesheet, it is shown under Computed tab.

---

**Why is it showing a value of 47px for base font-size of 32px?**

As I had mentioned earlier, there is no fixed computation logic for `line-height`. For the default font, when I set `font-size` as `2em` (`32px`) and the `line-height` explicitly as normal, the value that I get is `37px` (which is roughly equivalent to `line-height: 1.175`).

But when I use the ***Indie Flower*** (Google font) that you've used on `body`, the computed value for the `line-height` is equivalent to `47px`. You can see this in the below snippet where I have added three `h1` tags - one with no `line-height` setting, one with `line-height: normal` and another with `line-height: 47px`. All three are the same height. So, it seems like UA determines that such a big factor is required for this font unlike others.

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2em;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: red;
}
h1.withnumber {
  line-height: 47px;
}
h1.normal {
  line-height: normal;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" />
<h1>Abcd</h1>
<h1 class='normal'>Abcd</h1>
<h1 class='withnumber'>Abcd</h1>
```

Comment: Harry, is the list of all available properties the same for every element? If some of those properties are defined by UA stylesheet, then those properties also show in UA stylesheet section under the "Rules" tab. And the rest of the properties that are not defined by UA stylesheet or me diretcly, show their default values under the "Computed" tab. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Peter: Yes, you are correct. The full list of properties is almost the same for all elements. Whatever is defined in your CSS or in the UA stylesheet will appear under the Rules tab whereas those that are not defined (and are computed) will appear under Computed tab.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's super clear to me. Actually, I've got one more question. Are the default values for all properties the same in every browser?

Comment: @Peter: I am not very sure about that. UA stylesheets have no fixed rules but most of them should be the same (or atleast very similar).

Comment: @Peter: I am not very sure about that. UA stylesheets have no fixed rules but most of them should be the same (or atleast very similar).

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add I meant the values of those properties that are not defined by UA stylesheet.

Comment: @Peter: That again depends on what the spec says. For some fields the spec would have a standard value (like for example `display` for `span` will always be `inline` by default) and those will be same in all browsers but for some like `line-height`, spec just gives a suggestion and so each browser can treat it differently. I don't think we can get a list of the differences either. We will just have to handle them as they come.